# How to update the list only when certain conditions match

Tags: scala

I'm doing the following to map and update a list:

```
if (colors.map(_.id).contains(updated.id)) {
  val newColorList = updated :: colors.filterNot(s => s.id == updated.id)
  SomeMethod(newColorList)
}
else {
  this
}
```

The above works ok, However, I want to add a condition such as this: `If, and only if, the updated quantity is 0 then also update the enddate to todays date`.

I've done the following

```
if (color.map(_.id).contains(updated.id) && updated.quantity == 0) {
 val newColorList = updated.copy(enddate = Instant.now().toEpochMilli) :: colors.filterNot(s => s.id == updated.id)
}
else if (color.map(_.id).contains(updated.id)) {
 val newColorList = updated :: colors.filterNot(s => s.id == updated.id)
 SomeMethod(newColorList)
}
else {
  this
}
```

Is there a better way to do this than multiple if / else statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
val hasColor=color.map(_.id).contains(updated.id) 
newColorList = (hasColor,updated.quantity) match {
     case (true,0) => updated.copy(enddate = Instant.now().toEpochMilli) :: colors.filterNot(s => s.id == updated.id)
     case (true,_) => updated :: colors.filterNot(s => s.id == updated.id)
     otherwise => this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect` over the `colors` collection.

I assume there is a simple a case class `Color` like this

```
case class Color(id:String, quantity: Int, endDate : LocalDate)
```

And `updated` is also of type `Color`

```
import java.time.LocalDate

case class Color(id:String, quantity: Int, endDate : LocalDate)

val updated = Color("one", 0, LocalDate.now)

val colors = List(
             Color("one", 1, LocalDate.now().minusMonths(2)), 
             Color("two", 2, LocalDate.now.minusMonths(4)),
             Color("three", 3, LocalDate.now.minusMonths(6))
            )

  colors.collect{
  case e if e.id == updated.id && updated.quantity == 0 => 
      updated.copy(endDate =  LocalDate.now) //add element to new list, call method
  case e if e.id == updated.id => updated
  case e =>  e
}
//List(Color(one,0,2018-12-06), Color(two,2,2018-08-06), Color(two,2,2018-06-06))
```

Hope this helps you.